# Combine JQuery validate with JQuery Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have a form with three fields.  One of the first two inputs is required (can be either one or can be both) and the third field is always required.  For the first two, I have added them to a group to handle it.  This is my code so far

```
var validator = $("#my_form").validate({
    groups: {
        datagroup: "fieldOne fieldTwo"
    },
    rules: {
        fieldOne: {
            require_from_group: [1, '.datagroup'],
            email: true,
            maxlength: {
                param: 40,
                depends: function (element) {
                    var valTwo = $('#fieldTwo').val();
                    return !valTwo || (valTwo.length < 8) || (valTwo.length > 18);
                }
            }
        },
        fieldTwo: {
            require_from_group: [1, '.datagroup'],
            minlength: {
                param: 8,
                depends: function (element) {
                    var valOne = $('#fieldOne').val();
                    return !valOne || (valOne.length > 40);
                }
            },
            maxlength: {
                param: 18,
                depends: function (element) {
                    var valOne = $('#fieldOne').val();
                    return !valOne || (valOne.length > 40);
                }
            }
        },
        fieldThree: {

        }
    }
});
```

Here is my problem.  The above handles the first two inputs without a problem.  The third input is using JQuery Autocomplete to display a list to the user as they type.  I need to make sure that the submitted value is in that list.  I also need to make sure that a value has been provided.

I am not sure if I need to combine the third input into the group with the first two?  I am also not to sure how to make sure that the value is in my list.

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of your script make an invisible copy of your original name list:

```
var values = [];
$('#autocomplete').find('option').each(function(){
    values.push(this.value);
});
```

to avoid people adding names to the list, and to preserve the original name list for checking in your jQuery validator with:

```
            depends: function (element) {
                var valOne = $('#autocomplete').val();
                return !valOne || (values.indexOf(valOne) < 0);
            }
```